# Finding when columns are added- SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query, trigger, schema, table

In SQL Server is there any way to get information about when columns are created and which columns are new? Also, I need to find any change in columns, for example which columns' data type changed. I can get the creation and last modification date of tables, but for columns I could not find any query to do it. I tried using trigger, audit and other queries that I found in forums, but did not get the result I want. If someone knows the solution, help please. Third-party tools are acceptable, too.
Thanks in advance.
This is my trigger code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ColumnChanges
CREATE TABLE ColumnChanges (
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
DatabaseName NVARCHAR(100),
TableName NVARCHAR(100),
ColumnName NVARCHAR(100),
ActionType NVARCHAR(50),
OldDataType NVARCHAR(50),
NewDataType NVARCHAR(50),
Add_Modify_Date DATETIME
)


CREATE TRIGGER trg_ColumnChange_AfterAlter
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @EventData XML
SET @EventData = EVENTDATA()

DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ActionType NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @NewDataType NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Add_Modify_Date DATETIME

SET @DatabaseName = @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
SET @TableName = @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
SET @ActionType = 'ADDED/MODIFIED'
SET @NewDataType = @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/Alter/Columns/Column/DataTypeWithCollation)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
SET @Add_Modify_Date = GETDATE()

DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(100)
    SELECT @ColumnName = COLUMN_NAME    
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName

DECLARE @OldDataType NVARCHAR(100)
        SELECT @OldDataType = DATA_TYPE 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName


INSERT INTO ColumnChanges (DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName, ActionType,OldDataType,NewDataType, Add_Modify_Date)
VALUES (@DatabaseName, @TableName, @ColumnName, @ActionType, @OldDataType, @NewDataType, @Add_Modify_Date)
  END
```

Comment: And why didn't triggers or the Audit feature work?

Comment: @J.D. When I use trigger, it tracks when new column is added and get the date, but when I make changes in any column (for example, changing data type), it doesn't capture the column I changed. Instead of it,  it takes information of last added column in table. With audit, I didn't find anything that serves my purpose.

Comment: Both should be viable options. You should provide your trigger code, and someone may be able to help improve it.

Comment: I added the code. Thank you for suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final script. I created 2 triggers, one for tracking every new table and its columns, other for tracking new columns and altered(changing data type) columns. It works fine for me.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [Table_name]
CREATE TABLE [Table_name] (
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
DatabaseName NVARCHAR(100),
TableName NVARCHAR(100),
ColumnName NVARCHAR(100),
ActionType NVARCHAR(50),
DataType NVARCHAR(50),
Add_Modify_Date DATETIME
)

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_TableCreation 
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA()
DECLARE @TableName sysname

SET @TableName = @EventData.value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname')

INSERT INTO [Table_name] (DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName, ActionType, DataType, Add_Modify_Date)
SELECT @EventData.value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'sysname')
    , t.name
    , c.name
    , 'New table'
    , ty.name
    , @EventData.value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)[1]', 'datetime2')
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types ty on c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
WHERE t.name = @TableName
END


CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_ColumnChanges
ON DATABASE
FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @EventData XML = EVENTDATA()

INSERT INTO [Table_name] (DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName, ActionType, DataType, Add_Modify_Date)
SELECT e.value('(DatabaseName/text())[1]', 'sysname')
    , e.value('(ObjectName/text())[1]', 'sysname')
    , c.value('.', 'SYSNAME')
    , CASE 
        WHEN @EventData.exist('/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/Create') = 1 
        THEN 'Create'
        ELSE 'Alter'
        END
    , sc.DATA_TYPE
    , e.value('(PostTime/text())[1]', 'datetime2')
FROM @EventData.nodes('/EVENT_INSTANCE') e(e)
CROSS APPLY e.nodes('AlterTableActionList/*/Columns/Name') c(c)
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sc
       ON sc.TABLE_NAME = e.value('(ObjectName/text())[1]', 'sysname')
       AND sc.COLUMN_NAME = c.value('.', 'sysname')
END
```